# Find range of "goals" that aren't in comments with Regex

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

Maybe this is simple, but I haven't found a way to achieve the following behavior of regex. I want to match substrings that starts with `{!` and end with `!}`. I've tried the following regex: `{!.*!}`. But I want to exclude those, that starts with line `--`.

For example, let's say we have three lines:

```
-- Here is some comment {!0-goal!}
{!1-goal!}
Here is some text and {!3-goal!}
```

I want to match `{!1-goal!}` and `{!2-goal!}`, but not `{!0-goal!}`. Any suggestions?

**EXPANDED QUESTION:**

As it turned out, I will need to parse also this kind of "goals".

https://regex101.com/r/xL1eY3/5

How about that? I think that is probably few times harder to achieve, right? If someone can help me with that, I would really appreciate it. If not, I will write my own parser for that in Objective-C, but I want to avoid that for obvious reasons :)

Comment: What is the regex flavor?

Comment: Any flavor would be fine, but ultimately I will use it in OS X application. I just want to understand how to construct such regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a capturing group:

```
^(?!--).*(\{![^!]*!\})
```

Please pay attention this regex needs an `m` (multiline) flag. In Objective-C, that will be [NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/#//apple_ref/c/econst/NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines). And grab the value stored in the first captured group.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xL1eY3/4).

**EDIT**:

It is impossible to obtain the results for your updated input using only regex. The problem is that Objective C regex does not support variable-width look-behind. So, the solution you need is

- Process line by line
- If a line starts with `--`, discard it
- If a line does not start with `--`, apply the [`(?=(\{!(?:[^!]|\{![^!]*!\})*!\}))`](https://regex101.com/r/xL1eY3/7) regex.

Comment: If the strings to be tested are already pre filtered, there is no need in that precision. That construction that you are using often leads to catastrophical backtracking.

Comment: But that still doesn't match goals like `{!5-goal {!6-goal!} {!7-goal!}!}`. I'll wait for some more time and I'll accept your answer, since you correctly answered first question... Thanks!

Comment: Well, I have added another regex that collects all `{...}`s with only 1 nested level support. It captures these entities, not *matches*. You will have to access the capture group 1 to extract the contents. I hope that is enough. If not, we'll have to add more nested level support manually.

Comment: You are a regex god. Thanks! I'll skip lines that starts with `--` and I'll find goals with your regex. Then I'll look if there are some more nested goals... I think that would actually work! Thanks again. I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to match:

```
/^(?!\s*--).*({!(?:(?!!}).)+!})/gm
```

And extract `$1` (Group 1)

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nX6cI0/1)

Explanation:

- `^(?!\s*--)` lookahead assertion for starting with anything other than `--` or `(space) --`